# Use nginx as reverse proxy for all Docker containers

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, docker, nginx

I'm running Docker on my Raspberry Pi 4 with some containerized web apps and I want all traffic to go through nginx as reverse proxy.

My problem is that I can access the Docker container ports from any device in my network, i. e. I'm bypassing nginx.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myRaspi;

    location /cool {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/cool;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm forwarding the traffic for http://myRaspi/cool to http://localhost:5000/cool (a web app running inside a Docker container). At the moment, I can access both http://myRaspi/cool and http://myRaspi:5000/cool from any device in my network.

I followed the [official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host) and configured the following:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ext_if ! -s 192.168.174.0/24 -j DROP
```

Executing `sudo iptables --list` shows the new rule.
Since all of my network devices are in the subnet `192.168.175`, so I'd expect that now all traffic to both http://myRaspi/cool and http://myRaspi:5000/cool should not work (as I'm blocking everything except `192.168.174`, but I'm in `192.168.175`).
Unfortunately, this does not work: I can still access both http://myRaspi/cool and http://myRaspi:5000/cool.

After `sudo reboot`, the formerly created rule is gone and `sudo iptables --list` doesn't contain it anymore.

Since I'm still a novice to the Docker/Linux/nginx network world, I'd appreciate your help on how to configure Docker/nginx so that all traffic goes through nginx as reverse proxy and access to container ports from outside this Raspi is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was how I exposed the Docker ports when starting the container.

Before I was running containers like `-p 5000:5000`, now I'm using `-p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000`. This way the port is only exposed locally and therefore not accessible via http://myRaspi:5000/cool. No need to fiddle around with `iptables` manually.